# Mirroring Vertex Groups with Two Mirror Modifiers

Tags: rigging, mirror-modifier

I have a four-fingered claw that has a mirror modifier because it's symmetrical on both sides (two independent fingers on each side). However, this claw is also mirrored over a larger rig, so it has two mirror modifiers (one mirroring both sides of the claw, one mirroring the symmetrical claw over the larger rig). If possible, I would like to keep both mirror modifiers un-applied to make future work easier.

I can easily use ".L" and ".R" vertex group names to mirror vertex groups in one mirror modifier. However, in this case, I have two sets of mirror modifiers that each need to mirror different vertex groups so all eight fingers can be independently controlled.

Before I bite the bullet and apply one of the modifiers, is there a way (naming convention, etc) that I can use to make this work?

Comment: Some quick testing-- because this is an interesting question-- suggests that there was an attempt to make this work, but it was half-hearted, untested, and/or broke somewhere along the dev cycle.  If you want this feature, this seems like it would be an appropriate place for a bug report.  (You can check naming conventions via "autoname" feature, btw.  But, still broken.)  However, it doesn't seem very urgent to me, and it might not be something anybody fixes in time for the completion of your current project.

Comment: @Nathan You're probably right- I was just looking for a slightly quicker fix, but it's not a huge deal to work around. Interesting that this was partially implemented- could I ask how you tested it?

Comment: Sure, I used autoname to check conventions and made a cube-quadrant, with four bones.  It is doing *something* from front/back, just not the right thing.